# Wifi with WPA2-EAP MS-CHAPv2 authentication (username and password) during Debian installation

Tags: debian, wifi, system-installation, authentication, wpa2-eap

I am currently attempting to install Debian on my laptop computer. During the network configuration stage, I am prompted to "enter a passphrase for WPA/WPA2 PSK authentication". Unfortunately, I am on my school's network which requires both a username and a password, with the [MS-CHAPv2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access#MS-CHAPv2) authentication protocol. What should I enter at the prompt?

I have an Ubuntu computer which can connect to this network. Here are the contents of `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/NetworkName`:

```
[ipv6]
method=auto

[connection]
id=NetworkName
uuid=3e728a68-a877-4681-bc0e-1e64b2ff6434
type=802-11-wireless

[802-11-wireless-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-eap
auth-alg=open

[802-11-wireless]
ssid=NetworkName
mode=infrastructure
mac-address=84:A6:C8:A9:67:DA
security=802-11-wireless-security

[802-1x]
eap=ttls;
identity=username
phase2-auth=mschapv2
password-flags=1

[ipv4]
method=auto
```

Curiously enough, the password I enter to connect to NetworkName doesn't appear anywhere.

EDIT 2: Screenshot of network connection process (in a live-boot Ubuntu)
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is it possible that you are behind a [captive portal](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89630/how-to-sign-into-an-open-wireless-network/89705#89705) at your school?

Comment: @Nasha My experience with captive portals is that you must first open a browser and then connect; that doesn't happen with my network, so I don't think there's a captive portal.

Comment: I suppose, your school is using Eduroam. Is this right? What I'd do is to use another image with proper desktop to install debian. There pretty clear guides on installing debian this way on debian-wiki. Eduroam and such networks, using PEAP-MSCHAPv2 model of authorization, are pretty easy to configure with any distribution using NetworkManager.

Comment: @MikhailKrutov Actually Eduroam is a separate network I can connect to, and is reserved for visiting students/academics.

Comment: @AlessandroPower, still I assume that your network is using same authentication model, and IMO non-gui configuration for NetworkManager is a huge pain. Please provide more details on how do you connect & authenticate.

Comment: @MikhailKrutov I have included a screenshot of the network connection process in my answer.

Comment: Hopefully this gets answered as I am experiencing exactly the same.problem

Comment: Hopefully this gets answered; I am experiencing exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the live-cd has the full fledged `wpa-supplicant` package on board. I would suggest putting the bigger cd/usb image so you can install without network. After that you can configure `wpa_supplicant` with the following config:

```
network={
    ssid="eduroam"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    eap=TTLS
    identity="yourusername@institute.com"
    password="yourpassword"
    phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
}
```

instead of your password in plaintext you can change the entry with:
`password=hash:yourhash` where `yourhash` was obtained by running your password through:

```
echo -n "yourpassword" | iconv -t utf16le | openssl md4
```

Different institutes have different settings but this usually works.